# Do modern motherboards allow a PCI-E device to access ram without involving the CPU?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, memory

I'm doing research into novel Computer architectures and I need a clearer picture of how Memory Control works in a PC.

In short, I would like to know whether a PCI-E device, such as a GPU can access RAM and write to RAM without having to contact the CPU. Assume that the system knows where it is allowed to write to (kinda like a Virtual Machine), so that your system does not go haywire.

A short clear description of how the memory controller and CPU interact and how GPU's or PCI-E devices access system memory would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Gecko

Comment: DMA has been supported on even *ancient* motherboards.

Comment: In a lot of modern systems the memory controller is part of the CPU ...

Comment: There is a difference between [DMA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) and [Bus Mastering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_mastering). It sounds like this question refers to the latter (transfer initiated by the peripheral, not a device driver running on the CPU).

Comment: Read http://www.ertl.jp/~shinpei/papers/icpads13.pdf

Comment: If you consider the on-die memory controller is not part of the CPU, in which case, yes.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: That's arguable. From a purely elementary point of view, it isn't part of the CPU, it's on-die. But some consider it part of the CPU because it's on the same chip as the CPU. It's no more part of the CPU than an on-die GPU is part of the CPU. But some people consider the entire tower unit "the CPU" so nomatter how you look at it *someone* is going to be confuse.d

Comment: First off, thanks for all the responses. The reason why I asked this initially was because I was looking into reconfigurable computers, I was wondering whether one could run a new core on an FPGA supporting a virtual machine being run by a regular computer (Mobo built by a company like Asus), without being super inefficient by getting the CPU to do a lot of work to transfer data from Ram to FPGA.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, yes.  Originally ( in the 8086 ) it was called DMA, or Direct Memory Access.  Back then there was a dedicated DMA controller chip that the CPU had to program to transfer data between ram and peripherals, but at least as far back as the early PCI days ( and I *think* on the original ISA bus too, but I don't know of any devices that did ), peripherals themselves could also be bus masters, and transfer the data themselves.

They still normally require the cpu to tell them what parts of memory they should access, but some badly behaved devices, such as firewire controllers, open up DMA access to all of the system's ram at the behest of some external device on the firewire bus.  Some modern PCIe systems have smart PCIe bridges that can be programmed to perform address translation and access restrictions so the CPU can prevent devices connected behind them from accessing memory they shouldn't, but this currently seems restricted to big server type motherboards, not your typical desktop.

As for how, the PCI(e) bus allows any device to perform read/write to any address, be it in the main system ram ( typically controlled directly by the CPU these days ), or on some other device on the bus.  That is, one PCI(e) device can directly access the memory or registers of another PCI(e) device, or main system ram, without regard to where it is located.  The PCI(e) bridges route the request to the appropriate device, as they are configured ( by the system firmware/bios, and possibly later by the OS kernel ) to know what address ranges are "owned" by what device.

Comment: As for the original ISA bus. An Example is the Adaptec 1542CF SCSI hostadaptor. (16 bit ISA).

Comment: Hard to find a reliable citation, but serial ports using the 16550AFN UART supported DMA transfers. It looks like serial ports interfaced with the CPU via the ISA bus (this part is hard to cite). People old enough to remember when 14400 bps modems were the rage will remember that 16550A (at least) was pretty much a requirement, due to bugs in earlier UARTs.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, yea, I remember the 16550A ( also was great because it had a 16 byte FIFO ), but never heard of the AFN.

Comment: DMA already existed in the original IBM-PC architecture, with the ISA bus, like other architectures at the time, actually. So it's really an old concept. Don't you remember old soundcards on ISA slots required you to manually configure which DMA channel to use? Since no configuration was automatic back on those days, it's easy to remember (the pain).

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know whether a PCI-E device, such as a GPU can access RAM and write to RAM without having to contact the CPU.

Yes, it is called [bus mastering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_mastering).
The PCI/PCIe adapter can gain control of the bus, and compete for memory cycles.  The CPU, the DMA controller and bus masters could all be competeing for memory access.  The memory arbiter typically favors the CPU, which is typically assigned the highest priority.